# Hide "selected date" part of DatePicker

Tags: android, android-layout, android-datepicker

I have a custom dialog created where I have a DatePicker in the top portion of the View and a NumberPicker with AM/PM radio buttons in the lower part.  Works fine, but the DatePicker by default has this extra area at the top that shows the "selected date" as seen in below screen shot.  How can I remove it so all I have in the datepicker area is the calendar itself?  Is this possible?  The part I want removed is in yellow.

[image]

**datetime_dialog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/layoutDateTimePickerContainer"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/dialogDatePicker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/dialogTimePicker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />    

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radgrpDateTimePicker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:checkedButton="@+id/radDateTimePickerAM"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radDateTimePickerAM"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="AM"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radDateTimePickerPM"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="PM"/>

        </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/trDateTimePickerButtonsContainer"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDateTimePickerCancel"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:text="@string/general_cancel"
            android:textAllCaps="false"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDateTimePickerOkay"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/general_okay"
            android:textAllCaps="false"/>

    </TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please provide your custom dialog layout

Comment: @H.Brooks - XML provided as requested. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  You have to get reference to the LinearLayout of the DatePicker itself and then `.getChildAt(0)` and hide it.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.id.datetime_dialog);
DatePicker datePicker = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogDatePicker);
LinearLayout datePickerHeader = (LinearLayout) datePicker.getChildAt(0);
datePickerHeader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
dialogDatePicker.setTitle("");
```

Did you try like this:

```
DatePickerDialog dialog= new DatePickerDialog(this, dateSetListener, year, month, day);
dialog.setTitle("");
```

Comment: makes no difference. - the dialog title is not the problem it's the datepicker object itself within the dialog

Comment: i appreciate your thoughts, however this is using a Custom dialog as I specified in the post.  Not the DatePickerDialog class from Android.  Calling .setTitle on the dialog itself has no effect on the DatePicker object within the dialog's layout